# MySQL TLS auto generating exposes server ip

Tags: mysql, security, ssl

Is there any way to disable MySQL automatic TLS generating?

```
CN=MySQL_Server_8.0.25_Auto_Generated_Server_Certificate
CN=MySQL_Server_8.0.25_Auto_Generated_CA_Certificate
```

If i check my website with search.censys.io, i can find it's ip even though it's protected by CloudFlare because MySQL has generated a TLS certificate which exposed original server's ip